# How to use styled components with babel plugin in create-react-app that uses TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, styled-components

I have read the docs about styled components tooling. I have been able to use styled components without the babel plugin, but I have not been able to use style components with the babel plugin. From reading the docs, my impressions is that my best bet is to use the styled components macro.

My project uses

- un-ejected create-react-app
- TypeScript.

I have installed the following packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "styled-components": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^2.4.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.8.0"
  },
```

And here I use styled components in a `.tsx` file:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
[ts] Could not find a declaration file for module 'styled-components/macro'. '/Users/.../styled-components/dist/styled-components-macro.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I can get it to work by removing the `/macro` part of the import statement, but then I miss out on more readable class names during debugging as I understand it.

Comment: `@types/styled-components` does not know about the `styled-components/macro` module.  You can always write `declare module "styled-components/macro";` in a new `.d.ts` file to declare the module as type `any`, but that won't give you type information.  What does the API for the `styled-components/macro` module actually look like?  Is it really identical to that of the main `styled-components` module?

Comment: I believe it is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the `styled-components/macro` module as having API identical to `styled-components` by adding the following code to a `.d.ts` file in your project (not inside another module):

```
declare module "styled-components/macro" {
    export * from "styled-components";
    import styled from "styled-components";
    export default styled;
}
```

Consider proposing this declaration in a pull request to DefinitelyTyped (in the proper format: there you'll need a separate `macro.d.ts` file instead of using `declare module`) and perhaps the `@types/styled-components` maintainers will know whether it is fully accurate.